# Find All text within 1 level in HTML using Beautiful Soup - Python

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, findall

I need to use beautiful soup to accomplish the following

Example HTML

```
<div id = "div1">
 Text1
 <div id="div2>
   Text2
   <div id="div3">
    Text3
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to do a search over this to return to me in separate instances of a list

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

I tried doing a findAll('div'), but it repeated the same Text multiple times ie it would return

```
Text1 Text2 Text3
Text2 Text3
Text3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you problem is that `.text` also includes text from all the child nodes. You'll have to manually get only those text nodes that are *immediate* children of a node. Also, there might be multiple text nodes inside a given one, for example:

```
<div>
    Hello
        <div>
            foobar
        </div>
    world!
</div>
```

How do you want them to be concatenated? Here is a function that joins them with a space:

```
def extract_text(node):
    return ' '.join(t.strip() for t in node(text=True, recursive=False))
```

With my example:

```
In [27]: t = """
<div>
    Hello
        <div>
            foobar
        </div>
    world!
</div>"""

In [28]: soup = BeautifulSoup(t)

In [29]: map(extract_text, soup('div'))
Out[29]: [u'Hello world!', u'foobar']
```

And your example:

```
In [32]: t = """
<div id = "div1">
 Text1
 <div id="div2">
   Text2
   <div id="div3">
    Text3
   </div>
 </div>
</div>"""

In [33]: soup = BeautifulSoup(t)

In [34]: map(extract_text, soup('div'))
Out[34]: [u'Text1 ', u'Text2 ', u'Text3']
```