# How to get text from one level with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some web-page and I want to sort all text content by the levels. 
But I don't know what tags there will be.

```
html = BeautifulSoup("<a><b>text1</b><b>text2</b></a><c>text3</c>")
print(html.prettify())

#<html>
#  <body>
#      <a>
#         <b>
#           text1
#         </b>
#         <b>
#           text2
#         </b>
#      </a>
#      <c>
#         text3
#      </c>
#  </body>
#</html>
```

How can I get all text blocks with bs4?

```
level1 = ['text3']
level2 = ['text1', 'text2']
```

And so on... The structure of result can be different.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: This answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030605/find-all-text-within-1-level-in-html-using-beautiful-soup-python

And maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270805/python-beautifulsoup-level-1-only-text

Comment: @danielfranca, thanks! But the problem is that tags on the same level can be different (in those examples they extract everything from <div>).

Comment: Couldn't find anything to do exactly what you want, but maybe can you add a style or attribute to each level? Like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180783/how-to-use-python-beautiful-soup-to-get-only-the-level-1-navigabletext

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to resolve this problem is to use algorithm for searching tree (ex. Depth-first search)

```
from bs4 import NavigableString

def dfs(tree, level):
    for node in tree.children:
        if isinstance(node, NavigableString):
            if not node.string == '':
                print node.string, level
            return
        dfs(node, level + 1)

dfs(html, 0)
```

It will print

```
# text1 4
# text2 4
# text3 3
```

So, if it's necessary we can make a wrapper to save the results to dictionary. For example, like this:

```
from bs4 import NavigableString

def dfs(tree):
    level = 0
    levDic = {}

    dfs1(tree, level, levDic)
    return levDic


def dfs1(tree, level, levDic):
    for node in tree.children:
        if isinstance(node, NavigableString):
            if not node.string == '':
                if level in levDic.keys():
                    levDic[level].append(node.string)
                else:
                    levDic[level] = [node.string]
            return
        dfs1(node, level + 1, levDic)
    return

print dfs(html)
# {3: [u'text3'], 4: [u'text1', u'text2']}
```